# Evaluate $scope assignment

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Excuse me, I'm going to be direct here.
I have this function in my controller.

```
$scope.btnOptionSelect = function(id, value, target_id, target_value)  
{
    target_id = id;
    target_value = value;
}
```

And I have this snippet to call the function:

```
<button class="btnSelect" ng-click="btnOptionSelect(1,'Machinery',machine_edit.division_id, machine_edit.division_name)">Select</button>
```

What I'm trying todo is assign `target_id` as `id` and `target_value` as `value` which are:

```
$scope.machine_edit.division_id = id;
$scope.machine_edit.division_name = value;
```

I have no idea how to do this in AngularJS.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you set the scope variables directly in your method:

```
$scope.btnOptionSelect = function (id, value) {
    $scope.machine_edit.division_id = id;
    $scope.machine_edit.division_name = value;
}
```

Or do you need to pass them in your function?

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3275/
Here the target-values are passed as parameters. It gets a bit tricky when it's an objects values that pass into the function, as they are copies and not references directly to the values in the object. But you can pass in the object as a target, and the target-values as keys. The function also supports setting the target_vals directly if you don't pass in any target object.

Comment: Yes, I do need to pass the parameter as I need it for another purpose. The `target_id` and `target_value` could be another variable in the $scope.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. Check my new fiddle at the bottom. It gets a bit tricky when it's an objects values that pass into the function, as they are copies and not references directly to the values in the object. But you can pass in the object as a target, and the target-values as keys. The function also supports setting the target_vals directly if you don't pass in any target object.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign them directly

```
$scope.btnOptionSelect = function(target_id, target_value)  
{
    target_id = $scope.machine_edit.division_id;
    target_value = $scope.machine_edit.division_name;
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the parameter to the function, so that I can use it for another purpose.